# UFT 15.01 taking too long to read a grid table of a desktop application

Tags: grid, ui-automation, desktop-application, hp-uft

I am using UFT 15.01
to automate Desktop application (backend C++ and frontEnd .NET)

I am trying to read a grid table from the application using below code -

```
Set objGrid = SwfWindow("application").SwfWindow("screen").SwfObject("mobjGrid")

Set objGrid_Native = objGrid.Object.Sheets.Item(0)
strColumnCount = objGrid_Native.ColumnCount()
intGridRowCount = objGrid_Native.RowCount()

For intRowCounter = 0 To intGridRowCount - 1 Step 1
                    For intCount = 0 To strColumnCount - 1 Step 1
                        objGrid_Native.SetActiveCell intRowCounter, intCount
                        strValue = objGrid_Native.ActiveCell.Value()
                    Next
            Next
```

this code is working fine .

Problem :
the Grid has 139 rows and 25 columns , and above code takes more than 20 minutes to read the table and I need to iterate this for 10 different products which makes the execution time around 3 hours.

Is there any better way to minimize the execution time , please suggest.

Comment: Well, it completely depends on the API behind the SwfObjects.Object.Sheets.Item API. If supported, you could iterate over rows, not cells. Also, you could possibly pickup a cell's value without making it the active cell.

Comment: Cudos for operating software with such an efficiency in production :O

Comment: I guess your code above is incomplete. Everything just overwrites `strValue` - Do you need to read every cell?  What are you actually achieve with the table scan loop?